# Does vertical-align:middle; property work on <div> elements

Tags: html, css

I have a divison element whose `vertical-align` property is set to `middle` in the css. But, still the text in the divison appears on the top. Does this property work on divisons or not?

Following is the HTML

```
<div class="compare-table-column">Seller</div>
```

Following is the CSS

```
.compare-table-column {
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:36px;
  font:11px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: It won't work unless it's set to display: inline-block

Comment: omg css is full of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
line-height:36px;
```

if it is only one line of text

Comment: it worked :-) ... but i guess i should now learn a little about CSS and the inline, block elements etc :-P

Answer (score 4):

No, it only works on table-cell or inline elements.